# How to include multiple criteria in a single Where Clause SQL

Tags: sql, where-clause

The following query is almost complete. However, I am trying to include a condition in the where clause that takes into account values from three columns, whereby any record that matches the values stated across three columns will be excluded, any other records that have maybe one or two values but not all three are included in the output. So far, no luck:

```
SELECT
PRODUCT_ID,
UPC, 
CLEANSED_BRAND,
CLEANSED_TITLE,
DIVISION_ID,
DEPARTMENT_ID,
VENDOR_ID

FROM ATTRIBUTE
WHERE (DIVISION_ID <>37 AND DEPARTMENT_ID <>377 AND VENDOR_ID<>534)
```

For some reason, this WHERE clause is treating the AND as an OR in the sense that the output is excluding any record that has DIVISION_ID 37, or DEPARTMENT_ID 377, or VENDOR_ID 534.

It's intended to only exclude records where the DIVISION_ID = 37 AND DEPARTMENT_ID = 377 AND VENDOR_ID = 534.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and sample expected output

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Answer (score 5):

Try writing it like this:

```
WHERE NOT (DIVISION_ID = 37 AND DEPARTMENT_ID = 377 AND VENDOR_ID = 534)
```

The equivalent logic without the `NOT` is then:

```
WHERE DIVISION_ID <> 37 OR DEPARTMENT_ID <> 377 OR VENDOR_ID <> 534
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this on another thread:

In some cases where NOT does not work you can solve it using a simple case and where clause. This will exclude only those cases where `currentdoctype ='PUSH'` AND `CurrentDocEntry = 15`.

```
SELECT *,
CASE
WHEN currentdoctype ='PUSH' AND CurrentDocEntry = 15 THEN 'c1'
ELSE 'c2'
END AS com_con
FROM table_name
WHERE  BaseDocEntry=15 AND BaseDocType='PRRH' AND ItemCode='TestStudy2'
   AND WhseCode='01' AND com_con = 'c2';
```

It works. This was for DB2

Answer (score 0):

If PostgreSQL

```
WHERE (DIVISION_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID, VENDOR_ID) NOT IN ((37, 377, 534))
```

and you can easily add more exclusions as in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d30dd/1/0)